# Find the ratio of the shaded areas in a square and circle.

Tags: geometry, ratio

[image]

In both pictures, the circle has radius .

Find the ratio of the shaded area in (i) to the shaded area in (ii).

Answer in the form 1 : , where  is a decimal to 3 significant figures.

(i) Area of square = $4r^2$, area of circle = $r^2$, shaded area = $4r^2 - r^2$

(ii) Area of circle = $r^2$, area of square = $2r^2$, shaded area = $r^2 - 2r^2$

Going round in "circles" here to determine the ratio of these seemingly disparate fractions; any ideas?

Compare shaded area areas directly:

$\frac{4r^2 - r^2}{r^2 - 2r^2} = \frac{4 - }{ - 2} = 0.752$

Ratio 1 : 0.752

Comment: is the area of the square in the first part $r^2$? You might want to review that :) once that's done, just find the ratio of the shaded areas with each other directly.

Comment: Before solving the problem, let's get to basics. What is the area of a circle of radius $r$ and what is the side length of a square that is circumscribed by a circle of radius $r$?

Comment: Area of a circle of radius $r$ is not $2\pi r^2$

Comment: Firstly, it looks like you're supposed to calculate Area(i) and Area(ii) and then take the fraction/ratio of i:ii at the very end (not during each step).

Secondly, make sure you have the correct formulas for the area of a circle, isosceles right triangle, etc.

Comment: "*shaded fraction* $=4/(1-2\pi)$" $\;-\;$ Getting a negative number for the ratio of two areas should raise some red flags.

Comment: Sorry, i'd like to try and blame transcription/formatting errors for the glaring brain freeze, but probably won't wash :). Thanks for all the patient assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid possible confusion plot the areas together on either side of common circle periphery

[image]

Considering area outside and inside of the circle radius $r$ their ratio

$$ \frac {A_{outgreen}}{A_{inyellow}}= \frac {4r^2- \pi r^2}{\pi r^2- (\sqrt 2 r )^2}=  \frac {4-\pi}{\pi-2}=0.751938  $$